# Generating and Emailing excel files using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, excel

I am trying to generate excel file in PHP using ExcelWriterXML. I am able to create it but it is gicing me option to save it on system. But I want the generated file to be sent as an attachment in email. Can anyone please help me in this problem?
Or is there any other way except using PEAR to generate and email excel files dynamically in PHP?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The following tutorial will help you do what you want.

http://www.texelate.co.uk/blog/send-email-attachment-with-php/

PS: Read also the comment there are some valuable posts :)

Answer (score 0):

If ExcelWriterXML has no facility to store the result in a variable, you can use PHP ob_start, ob_get_contents, etc to temporarily capture output to a variable and then pass that to an emailer. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php